# tastypie and x-editable using patch

Tags: javascript, django, tastypie, x-editable

I almost have x-editable working with the django API built with tastypie thanks to various other answers on stackoverflow, but not quite.

Here is the html:

```
 <a href="#" id="field_name" class="editable"
                                 data-name="name"
                                 data-pk="{{ object.id }}"
                                 data-value="{{ object.name }}"
                                 data-title="Meeting Name">
                            {{ object.name }}</a>
```

and the javascript:

```
   $('.editable').on('init', function(e, edt) {
        edt.options.url = '/api/v1/update_meeting/' +edt.options.pk;
    });
    $('.editable').editable({
        mode: 'inline',
        ajaxOptions: {
            type: 'PATCH'
        },


        success: function(response, newValue) {

            // nothing to do
        }

    });
```

And the tastypie resource:

class UpdateMeetingResource(ModelResource):

```
class Meta:
    queryset = Meeting.objects.all()
    resource_name = 'update_meeting'
    limit = 0
    include_resource_uri = False
    list_allowed_methods = ['get','patch',]
    detail_allowed_methods = ['get', 'patch']
    serializer = urlencodeSerializer()
    authentication = Authentication()
    authorization = Authorization()
```

My only problem is that the field name gets updated with "name" and not the value in data-value.  Before I put in the data-name attribute, it was setting the value to "field_name".

I could fix this by simply changing the patch-detail method in my tastypie resource, but it would be nice to get it working without doing that.

Comment: Have solved this temporarily by subclassing patch-detail.  Have a better solution in mind and will document here when I have it working...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem was that the patch being sent was a key value pair and that was not being recognised by tastypie, but a quick modifiation to hydrate fixes it.  Maybe not the best solution but here is what is working for me:

The html:

```
    <a href="#" id="name" class="editable editable_default_setup"
      data-title="Name"
      data-pk="{{ object.pk }}"
      data-value="{{ object.name }}"
      data-placeholder="Meeting Name" >
      {{ object.name }}</a>
```

The javascript:

```
$('.editable').on('init', function(e, edt) {
    edt.options.url = '/api/v1/meeting/' + {{ object.id }};
});

$.fn.editable.defaults.ajaxOptions = {type: "PATCH"};

$('.editable_default_setup').editable();
```

Setting up the resource:

```
 class Meta:
    queryset = Meeting.objects.all()
    include_resource_uri = False
    resource_name = 'meeting'
    limit = 100
    allowed_methods = ['post','put','get','options','patch', 'delete']
    detail_allowed_methods = ['patch']
    authentication = Authentication()
    authorization = Authorization()
    serializer = urlencodeSerializer()
    always_return_data=True
```

The important bit, Modification to the tastypie resource:

```
def hydrate(self, bundle):

    if bundle.request.method == "PATCH":
        # data is supplied by x-editable in format {u'pk': u'1170', u'name': u'owner', u'value': u'5', u'format': u'json'}
        # apply this value to the obj and return

        field_name = bundle.data['name']
        field_value = bundle.data['value']

        # the use of name is unfortunate as it can override a field called name, so put it back to original value unless updating it
        # do the same with value, just in case

        bundle.data['name'] = getattr(bundle.obj, 'name', None)
        bundle.data['value'] = getattr(bundle.obj, 'value', None)

        # now set the attribute field_name to field_value so object will update
        bundle.data[field_name] = field_value
        setattr(bundle.obj, field_name, field_value)


 return bundle
```